# How to query a specific header from a list of urls without security prompts

Tags: powershell, last-modified, invoke-webrequest

I have a long list of urls for which I want to check the `last-modified` header

The script below works well, however for some pages I get this popup, which of course slows down the whole process as I need to click 'No' every time:

[image]

To get around this, I added the `-UseBasicParsing` paramater (commented below)

This prevents the security warning, but also prevents `last-modified` header from appearing in the response

Is there any way around this?

```
$urls = @(
    "https://www.google.com/",
    "https://www.bassie.com/"
)

function Get-LastModified($url) {
    $WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest $url -TimeoutSec 10 # -UseBasicParsing
    $members = $WebResponse | Get-Member
    $parsedHtml = $WebResponse.ParsedHtml

    $output = $parsedHtml | Select lastModified
    return $output
}

foreach($url in $urls) {
    if ($url -match "http://" -or $url -match "https://") {
        $lastModified = Get-LastModified $url
    
        Write-Host "--------------------------------------"
        Write-Host $url
        Write-Host $lastModified
        Write-Host "--------------------------------------"
    }
}
```

Comment: Without IE: `(iwr "https://www.google.com/" -UseBasicParsing).Headers['Date']`

Comment: When I ran the code in PS7 there was no lastModified value.  When I run it in PS5 the value is there, but it looks like the local time when the operation was performed.  In either case it ran without a security warning.  What is the end goal of retrieving that value?

Comment: @ScottHeath The idea is to get the last date/time which the page was updated, where the host makes that availble. Security warning only appears for ceratin urls, but it seems this is potentially fruitless as I always get either nothing or current date/time

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That does seem to work, but not when passing in `Last-Modified` header name (they are all empty - where specifying as in OP returns current date/time - (also wrong))